# Is there a simpler way check the length of a list and output the correct if statement?

Tags: python

The amount of variables in the list will vary so it could increase or decrease, I want to convert the variables in the list to strings depending on the number of variables in the list. I know that in this example I provided they are strings but in my code the variables in the list are not strings. Below I use if, elif statements to convert the appropriate amount of variables but is there a easier way to write this?

Variables in the list are defined here

```
a = 'apple'
b = 'banana'
c = 'cat'
d = 'dog'
e = 'eat'
f = 'fart'
g = 'game'
```

The list is created and the length of the list is assigned to x

```
list_1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
x = len(list_1)
```

The if, elif statements that check the list for the the length and then converts the variables into strings. This part is what I want to simplify or write in a more efficient way.

```
    if x == 1:
    a_new = (str(list_1[0]))
elif x == 2:
    a_new = (str(list_1[0]))
    b_new = (str(list_1[2]))
elif x == 3:
    a_new = (str(list_1[0]))
    b_new = (str(list_1[1]))
    c_new = (str(list_1[2]))
elif x == 4:
    a_new = (str(list_1[0]))
    b_new = (str(list_1[1]))
    c_new = (str(list_1[2]))
    d_new = (str(list_1[3]))
elif x == 5:
    a_new = (str(list_1[0]))
    b_new = (str(list_1[1]))
    c_new = (str(list_1[2]))
    d_new = (str(list_1[3]))
    e_new = (str(list_1[4]))
elif x == 6:
    a_new = (str(list_1[0]))
    b_new = (str(list_1[1]))
    c_new = (str(list_1[2]))
    d_new = (str(list_1[3]))
    e_new = (str(list_1[4]))
    f_new = (str(list_1[5]))
else:
    a_new = (str(list_1[0]))
    b_new = (str(list_1[1]))
    c_new = (str(list_1[2]))
    d_new = (str(list_1[3]))
    e_new = (str(list_1[4]))
    f_new = (str(list_1[5]))
    g_new = (str(list_1[6]))
```

Comment: There is definitely a simpler way. Although, could you provide the output you expect, it is hard to figure out what you are trying to do with your code

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you have a lot of variables that only differ by one character or digit, then you should not be using a lot of variables, and you should instead be using a single dictionary or list.

Comment: expected output

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: using "list_1 = [str(x) for x in list_1]" did it, I tried using this earlier but I guess I must have typed something incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you don't need the `str` conversion (at least not in your example). Otherwise you can use:

```
list_1 = [str(x) for x in list_1]
```

For the other part you can use the star `*[1, 2]` syntax and the multiple assignment `a, b = 1, 2`.

```
if x == 1:
    a_new = *list_1
elif x == 2:
    a_new, b_new = *list_1
elif x == 3:
    a_new, b_new, c_new = *list_1
```

Though you might want to consider just using a dictionary

```
{'a_new': a, 'b_new': b}
```